# Set aromatic ring thickness in Chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I use `\newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em}` and
`\setbondstyle{line width = \bondwidth}` to make my bonds a bit thicker, however, this doesn't seem to affect aromatic rings, leading to a slightly irritating mismatch.

[image: Current Look]

I'd like to make the width match that of my lines, preferably with some kind of global configuration setting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the \setchemfig{} command as describe in the notice p.4

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\setchemfig{chemfig style={line width=.25pt}}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{**6(------)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use

```
\chemfig{-[:0]**[,,line width=.25pt]6(---(-)---)}
```

line width controls the thickness of the circle.

Comment: I tried adding `\setchemfig{chemfig style={line width=\bondwidth}}` however I still end up with the image seen in my original post. I imagine the aromatic ring's thickness needs to be set differently.

Comment: Did you update your distribution ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm using TeX Live 2018.

Comment: The package is perhaps outdated. You could update thé package chemig with the Package Manager or use a command prompt and write sudo tlmgr update --all if your OS is Linux.

Comment: I was using chemfig v1.31, I updates to 1.32 and that fixed it :)